# What does slice1 = arr2d[0:1,0:2] do?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, slice

I'm learning how to create a slice for an array and I used

```
slice1 = arr2d[0:1,0:2]
```

and it gave me

```
[[1 2]]
```

can someone explain what happened here?

Comment: This is answered well by a picture, so I'd suggest a search for "numpy slice" and look for images of arrays with regions outlined in color. Otherwise, a good answer here will just be reproducing those pictures. Eg, [here](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html#indexing-and-slicing) and scroll down a bit for the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using numpy in python 3 is that right? It will be also useful to describe what arr2d is but I assume it is a 2d array. I will just assume arr2d is as follow:

```
arr2d = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[10,20,30,40]])
```

The operation you are trying to do is called slicing, arr2d[0:1,0:2] will get the first row of the matrix and the first and second column in arr2d which is [1,2]. In this case, arr2d[0:1,0:2] will be the same as arr2d[0,0:2]

This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_slicing.asp) explains slicing pretty well you can have a look.